# Passing a value from Window 2 to Main window when double click WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have 2 Windows, Main window has a button that opens Window 2.

Windows 2 contains datagrid holding a list of values, The user double-click to select a row from the list and closes Window 2 filling some text boxes with the data of the selected row

Some example code I have:

```cs
public class User {
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set;}
}
```

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    Window2 window = new(DataToRetrieve);
    window.ShowDialog();
    
    //Get data here to and print in the text boxes
    //textbox.Text = itemRetrieved.Something;

}
```

My method for grabbing the item from the datagrid with MouseDoubleClick event

```cs
private void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
  if (sender != null)
  {
    DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
    if (grid != null && grid.SelectedItems != null && grid.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
    {
       DataGridRow dgr = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem) as DataGridRow;
       DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)dgr.Item;
    }
  }
}
```

How should able to send over my main window the data of the list picked to my main window?

Comment: You haven't described an actual problem. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to ask a question properly. You might start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example add a property to the second window where you store the selected data, e.g.:

```
public DataRowView SelectedData { get; private set; }

private void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
        if (grid != null && grid.SelectedItems != null && grid.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            DataGridRow dgr = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem) as DataGridRow;
            this.SelectedData = (DataRowView)dgr.Item;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just use this property in the `MainWindow`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    Window2 window = new(DataToRetrieve);
    window2.ShowDialog();

    // Get data here...
    textbox.Text = window2.SelectedData["someColumn"].ToString();

}
```

Comment: oh, thanks a lot, even with the private set, yeah it works and helped me with the trouble